# How to modify Ubuntu Precise .iso preseed?

Tags: 12.04, iso, preseed, custom-distributions, debian-installer

I'm trying to modify the installation sequence of Ubuntu Precise. I need add a repository package inside the iso.

I make my own apt repository mirror and add my own packages with

```
reprepro includedeb
```

Then I run

```
mkisofs
```

to make my .iso an include in the final iso.

Then I build my customized debian-installer including `iso-scan` udeb package. After that, I build the fake final iso with: `grub-mkrescue`

In the process of installation when the iso-scan work takes place it can't find the repo.iso file and installation process stops.

I have searched but I only found things related to debian-installer. I don't know how to do it in Ubuntu Alternate or similar installations.

Comment: I could write a very good answer about this, but I think you should elaborate a bit more on what you've tried. Be specific. Oh, and solely preseeding isn't going to include a custom package - you *can* add packages from the regular repositories though (if an internet connection is available at install time). Hint: the server and alternate CDs are using `debian-installer`.

Comment: For a Wubi install? You should be able to modify the `preseed.cfg` file using `d-i preseed/late_command ...`

Comment: @bcbc I know that. But I need to include a .iso image of a repository to enable a local instalation without internet connection.

Comment: @gertvdijk I had elaboret my question a bit more, thanks for the sugestion.